# Incorrect syntax near a var

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, heidisql

I'm working with HeidiSQL on SQL Server, trying to create an after insert trigger, here is the code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_After_Insert_User ON User1 AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @userName varchar(24)
    declare @userLName varchar(20)
    declare @userSex varchar(10)

    select @userName = i.name from inserted i
    select @user1LName = i.lastname from inserted i
    select @userSex = i.gender from inserted i

    IF @userSex = 'Male'
       @userSex = 'M'
    ELSE
        @userSex = 'F'

    INSERT INTO db2.dbo.user2(name, lastname, gender) 
    VALUES (@legajoName, @legajoName, @legajoSexo)
END
```

The error I get:

> Incorrect syntax near '@userSex'

I've tried it without the IF sentence, and it worked, so the problem is there. But I need that sentence, because the 'gender' field from second table its 'char' type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed the `SET`:

```
IF @userSex = 'Male'
   SET @userSex = 'M'
ELSE
   SET @userSex = 'F'
```

In SQL this is invalid syntax for assigning a value to a variable: `@userSex = 'M'`.

Reference

### [SET @local_variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259193(v=sql.80).aspx)

> Sets the specified local variable, previously created with the DECLARE @local_variable statement, to the given value.
>
> SET { { @local_variable = expression }

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger has a major logical flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row inserted. This is a common but major problem. In sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. You can change your whole trigger to be a single set based insert and drop all those scalar variables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_After_Insert_User ON User1 AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db2.dbo.user2(name,lastname,gender) 
    select name, lastname, left(gender, 1) --or you could use a case expression here
    from inserted
END
```